# How to create a token input where the user also can add new tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, jquery-tokeninput

Currently, I'm using the gem `"acts_as_taggable_on_steroids".`
Everything working fine. Now I'd like to add `tokeninput` to this "tag input box"
All the tags existing should be displayed here as `candidate tag.` when the user input 1st word.
and those tags have to be delimited by `" "(space)`

How can I make both `"acts_as_taggable_on_steroids"` and token input working??
Any good instruction to archive these?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RailsCast #258.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?view=asciicast)
It's useful, fast and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved one issue which is adding new tag using the things given in this url

https://github.com/Mean-CJ/jquery-tokeninput/commit/ecb8b04df6df21b1a892187a5bcf94ff7b8d15d1

Which are commenting

```
//$(this).val("");
// Adding these two lines
newToken = {'id':$(this).val(),'name':$(this).val()};   
add_token(newToken);
```

In the else part of

```
case KEY.COMMA:
```

In the js file